# How to set preferred domain on website in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I feel like this is such a simple thing but I am just blanking on this.

Where can I set up my preferred domain. I want Google to view `mysite.com` instead of `www.mysite.com`

I'm following this guide
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en

but I cannot find a gear icon. Is this article out of date?

Where can I find the 'www vs non www' settings in google analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to be looking in the wrong tool. It's in [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) (formerly Google Webmaster Tools), not in Google Analytics.

The page you linked to is a "Search Console" Help document.